# Add data input field instead in hardcode values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, input, tensorflow.js

```
<html>

<head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <!-- Get latest version at https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.11.2">
    </script>
</head>

<body>


    <div id="output_field"></div>

</body>
<script>
    async function learnLinear() {
        const model = tf.sequential();
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({
            units: 1,
            inputShape: [1]
        }));
        model.compile({
            loss: 'meanSquaredError',
            optimizer: 'sgd'
        });

        const xs = tf.tensor2d([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 1]);
        const ys = tf.tensor2d([-3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7], [6, 1]);

        await model.fit(xs, ys, {
            epochs: 1000
        });


        document.getElementById('output_field').innerText = model.predict(tf.tensor2d([15], [1, 1]));
    }
    learnLinear();
</script>
<html>
```

This is a simple code for tensorflow.js I need to change this to get values from user input and show predicted value. I try different ways but not a success.
Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: It would help, if you'd described the user inputs in details, even maybe post some code to show the inputs. Also, it's not clear which values you want to replace, all of them (22 pcs)?

Comment: @Teemu   model.predict(tf.tensor2d([15], [1, 1])) I need to replace this 15 as a input value

Comment: It looks like you know how to refer an element with an `id`, where have you got stuck when trying?

Comment: I want to add like input filed and submit button after that I want to show predicted value